# WPF change color of Rectangle Fill in code

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Hey all I am new at WPF's and am in need of changing the color of a Rectangle fill in a WPF.

Currently I have this:

```
<Rectangle Fill="{Binding aColor}" RadiusY="5" RadiusX="5">
    <Rectangle.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0"/>
    </Rectangle.Effect>
</Rectangle>
```

I am not sure how to go about using that binding above within code.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it!

C#:

```
System.Drawing.Color c = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");
System.Windows.Media.Color color = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(c.R, c.G, c.B);
aColor.Color = color;
```

XAML:

```
<Rectangle RadiusY="5" RadiusX="5">
  <Rectangle.Fill>
     <SolidColorBrush x:Name="aColor"/>
  </Rectangle.Fill>
  <Rectangle.Effect>
     <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0"/>
  </Rectangle.Effect>
</Rectangle>
```

Answer (score 2):

Fill property is of type Brush , so you cant bind color directly,

Do something like this,

```
<Rectangle Width="100"
           Height="100">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding color}"/>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

Otherway is  you can implement your Color-To-Brush converter. Like [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2f40843a-b7b6-4613-ad22-367ca855e765/binding-fill-color-of-rectangle-to-a-color)